# Android Studio creating tabs for a app , beginner

Tags: java, android

I am currently working on a project and I want to make different tabs. Like the app flipboard[image]

I am making my app in android studio and I am done with the "home page", but I don't know how to make a new tab.
I also want to make like a sign in page for when people first open the app like facebook.
For lasst I also want it to have google maps in it.
But I don't know how to do that either.
So my question is how do you do that or is there a book / website where you can get all the information about this and android studio in general.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too broad and I don't think anyone is going to write up the code for you. A simple google search has given me this:

For Facebook login, implement Facebook SDK:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started

Google Maps:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/?hl=en

Google's SDKs also support user login, which you could use together with Facebook.

For "creating new tabs", apparently I can't post more than two links in my post since I don't have enough reputation, but google "android how to make new activity".

Answer (score 0):

For the Tabs you can use the Android Action Bar:

[Tutorial](http://www.101apps.co.za/index.php/articles/tab-navigation-tutorial.html)

For the Map you can use the Google Maps API, its easy to understand ;)

[Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/intro?hl=de)

Answer (score 0):

I am using   [this guide](http://www.android4devs.com/2015/01/how-to-make-material-design-sliding-tabs.html)   based on `SlidingTabLayout` . And i think it will help you perfectly .